# Check an element to see if it contains an image. If so, play a sound. Play a different sound if no image

Tags: javascript

I have a table of records, some of those records will have an image in a `<td>` element.

If that element does NOT contain an image I want to play the default sound, but if an image exists in the element play a different sound.
Here is what I have tried, but it doesn't work, it just plays the default sound.

the result was, it only plays the default sound even though there is an image in some of the other element.

```js
function play_alert_audio() {
  var audio_element = document.getElementById("alert_audio");
  var tab_element = document.getElementById("record");

  for (i = 0; i <= tab_element.childNodes.length - 1; i++) {
    // check if the element is an IMG (image type).
    if (tab_element.childNodes[i].tagName == 'IMG') {
      var audio_element = document.getElementById("alert_audio1");
    }
  }

  if (audio_element.paused) {
    audio_element.play();
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Record 1:</td>
    <td id='record' onclick='play_alert_audio()'><img src='record.jpg'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Record 2:</td>
    <td id='record' onclick='play_alert_audio()'>Text Only here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Record 3:</td>
    <td id='record' onclick='play_alert_audio()'>Text Only here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Record 4:</td>
    <td id='record' onclick='play_alert_audio()'><img src='record.jpg'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<audio id="alert_audio" src="alert.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" loop="loop"></audio>
<audio id="alert_audio1" src="marimba.wav" type="audio/wav" loop="loop"></audio>
```

Comment: Play audio on hovering table cell or what ?

Comment: You'd better create a minimal runnable demo, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I believe it's got something to do with the naming of the element.  Since each record is different and some records will have an image. I am wondering whether the element name needs to change for each record.

Comment: do not use my answer to modify your question code

Comment: sorry.....I am very new here.

Comment: Some advice for you: first, format your code when adding the question; second, make your code a minimal runnable demonstration of the question; third, make sure you clearly describe your problem and how you are trying to solve it ;

Comment: thanks xgqfrms.....I thought I did that.  But obviously not the same as the site requires.

Comment: you are missing a double quote: `loop="loop</audio>`

Comment: You are right, but I think that's just a typo, not the main problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you delegate you can just use relative addressing

I changed ID to class and added a tbody with an ID instead

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const audio_element1 = document.getElementById('alert_audio');
  const audio_element2 = document.getElementById('alert_audio1');
  document.getElementById('recordBody').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target.closest('td.record');
    if (!tgt) return;
    let audio_element = tgt.closest('tr').querySelector('img') ? audio_element1 : audio_element2;
    console.log(audio_element)
    if (audio_element.paused) {
      audio_element.play();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="recordBody">
    <tr>
      <td>Record 1:</td>
      <td class="record"><img src="record.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Record 2:</td>
      <td class="record">Text Only here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Record 3:</td>
      <td class="record">Text Only here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Record 4:</td>
      <td class="record"><img src="record.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<audio id="alert_audio" src="alert.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" loop="loop</audio">
<audio id="alert_audio1" src="marimba.wav" type="audio/wav" loop="loop"></audio>
```

Comment: thank you mplungjan......it looks like it might be the answer.  Although, I must be entering it wrong in my page.  Will let you know.

Comment: Remember the `<tbody id="recordBody">`

Comment: yes...I added that ok......but unfortunately your code doesn't suit my purpose.  I have found the element needs to have a unique id name, but I am trying to work out how to do that...

Comment: Which element needs what unique ID and why? I answered the question as it was posed. As asked, there are no need for IDs